# error Reason: no suitable image found. when run on device

Tags: swift, xcode8

I've created a project in Xcode 8. When I run it on the simulator, it works fine, but when I run it on a real device it doesn't run.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib 
>     Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/871C44C1-B21B-418C-840E-DAB05DA1D542/Test03.app/Test03 
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: 
>    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/871C44C1-B21B-418C-840E-DAB05DA1D542/Test03.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/871C44C1-B21B-418C-840E-DAB05DA1D542/Test03.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

Answer (score 0):

**Following the below steps**

1. remove your app from the device
2. clean your project
3. remove derived data (xcode->preferences->Loactiona->click on red part->and remove all file from DerivedData)

[image]
4. build and run in your device i think run

Comment: i cant understand how remove derived data and i cleaned project but doesnt work

Comment: check the updated answeer @shazde2025

Comment: no this solution is useless.